# Display Popup with ProgressBar in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, popup, progress-bar

How can I display my progress bar through pop up and automatically close if process is finished. Here is my code.

```
 Task<ProgressForm> task = new Task<ProgressForm>() {
            @Override 
            public ProgressForm call() throws InterruptedException{
                ProgressForm pf = new ProgressForm();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    pf.activateProgressBar(this);
                    updateProgress(i, 10);
                }
            return pf;                
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                ProgressForm pf = (ProgressForm)task.getValue();
                pf.getDialogStage().close();
            }
        });

        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.run();
```

Progress form class:

```
private final Stage dialogStage;
private final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
private final ProgressIndicator pin = new ProgressIndicator();

public ProgressForm() {
    dialogStage = new Stage();
    dialogStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    dialogStage.setResizable(false);
    dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    // PROGRESS BAR
    final Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("alerto");

    pb.setProgress(-1F);
    pin.setProgress(-1F);

    final HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.setSpacing(5);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hb.getChildren().addAll(pb, pin);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hb);
    dialogStage.setScene(scene);
}

public void activateProgressBar(final Task task) throws InterruptedException {
    pb.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    pin.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    dialogStage.show();
}

public Stage getDialogStage() {
    return dialogStage;
}
```

The problem with this code is

1. if i use .show(), displaying pop up is smooth but NO PROGRESS BAR.
2. if i use .showAndWait(), displaying pop up requires manual exit for the pop up to close BUT Progress bar displays.

Any thoughts/ideas about this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two rules for multithreading in JavaFX are:

1. Code which modifies the UI (creates a `Stage` or changes properties
   of nodes that are part of a scene graph) **must** be executed on the
   JavaFX Application thread. Violating this rule will either throw
   `IllegalStateException`s or result in unpredictable behavior.
2. Code which takes a long time to execute **should** be executed in a background thread (i.e. not the FX Application Thread). Violating this rule will cause the UI to become unresponsive.

Your code violates the first rule, because it calls the `ProgressForm` constructor in a background thread. You should set up the UI first, show the dialog, and then start the background thread.

Note that there is no need to repeatedly bind the `progress` properties of the progress bar and indicator to the `progress` property of the task. Once it is bound, it will remain bound until and unless you unbind it.

It's quite hard to fix your code as it stands, because your background task doesn't actually do anything that takes any time. Here's a version of what you're doing with just a pause:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class ProgressDialogExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            ProgressForm pForm = new ProgressForm();

            // In real life this task would do something useful and return 
            // some meaningful result:
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        updateProgress(i, 10);
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                    updateProgress(10, 10);
                    return null ;
                }
            };

            // binds progress of progress bars to progress of task:
            pForm.activateProgressBar(task);

            // in real life this method would get the result of the task
            // and update the UI based on its value:
            task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                pForm.getDialogStage().close();
                startButton.setDisable(false);
            });

            startButton.setDisable(true);
            pForm.getDialogStage().show();

            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(startButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static class ProgressForm {
        private final Stage dialogStage;
        private final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        private final ProgressIndicator pin = new ProgressIndicator();

        public ProgressForm() {
            dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            dialogStage.setResizable(false);
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            // PROGRESS BAR
            final Label label = new Label();
            label.setText("alerto");

            pb.setProgress(-1F);
            pin.setProgress(-1F);

            final HBox hb = new HBox();
            hb.setSpacing(5);
            hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            hb.getChildren().addAll(pb, pin);

            Scene scene = new Scene(hb);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);
        }

        public void activateProgressBar(final Task<?> task)  {
            pb.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
            pin.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
            dialogStage.show();
        }

        public Stage getDialogStage() {
            return dialogStage;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: good day! tried your code but seems like the stage is not showing my progressbar.

the look of it: http://pasteboard.co/2zCr2Qbx.png

Comment: You ran the exact code I posted? It worked fine for me. What JDK and OS are you using?

Comment: was able to resolve a lil of my problem. right now i have to fix how to avoid UI block whenever i call waitFor for a certain process. seems like my progress bar is not showing due to waitFor().

Comment: waitFor() is a blocking call, so if you call it on the FX Application Thread, the UI will become unresponsive (rule 2 above). If the UI is unresponsive, it will not render, so you don't see the contents of the dialog. There is no need to call waitFor(). If there is code you need to execute after the task is done, execute it in the onSucceeded handler.

Comment: sorry took me so long to reply to you. after several trial and errors and rereading again your comment, finally i was able to understand the flow. sorry cant upvote your answer because i need 15 reputations but nevertheless your answer was superb!

Comment: Something interesting happens when updateProgress(i, 10); goes into updateProgress(i, 100/i); try it out.

Comment: @WesosdeQueso What do you mean? Surely that would just interpolate the progress along a quadratic?

Comment: It just keeps bouncing and never stops.

Comment: @WesosdeQueso The integer division by zero in the first iteration confuses it. Use `100.0/i` instead of `100/i`.

Comment: Thank You Very much @James_D for giving perfect working code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use controlsfx library to display this easily

```
private void progressDialogue(){
    copyWorker = createWorker();
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(copyWorker);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    dialog.setGraphic(null);
    //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    //dialog.setContentText("Files are Uploading");
    //dialog.setTitle("Files Uploading");
    //dialog.setHeaderText("This is demo");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);
    dialog.setGraphic(null);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    new Thread(copyWorker).start();        
    dialog.showAndWait();
}


public Task createWorker() {
    return new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                updateMessage("2000 milliseconds");
                updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

now you need to call the method progressDialogue();

the code is from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK_1YGLI9ig